# content-security-policy is blocking content that I need

Tags: apache, aws-lambda, content-security-policy

I have the following header:

```
   headers['content-security-policy'] = [{

        key:   'Content-Security-Policy',

        value:  "default-src 'self' https://xxxxx.com/; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com/; img-src 'self' data: https://www.google-analytics.com/ https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/; script-src 'self' https://www.googletagmanager.com/ https://www.google-analytics.com/ https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/ 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com/ 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'none'"

    }];
```

Then i am testing my app, but the content is blocked:

I check using chrome in console:

```
Refused to load the image 'https://www.google.com/ads/ga-audiences?v=1&aip=1&t=sr&_r=4&tid=UA-120141483-1&cid=1976094765.1541777205&jid=1662457520&_v=j71&z=121168835' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data: https://www.google-analytics.com/ https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/".

loader.js:219 Refused to load the script 'https://www.gstatic.com/charts/45.2/loader.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://www.googletagmanager.com/ https://www.google-analytics.com/ https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/ 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'".
```

What is the problem with my header, I need to change or add something?

I am tyrying to test with a lambada in aws or deploying in apache2

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you look into the headers, it says that the img-src has 'self' in it. It means that the image src's domain has to be the same domain as that of the app you are running. So, if the image is www.abc.com/image=hello.jpg and you have the header as 'self', that image can only be displayed to abc.com domain.

Comment: Then, what value, need to replace de self o only removing the self works?

Comment: Can you try to img-src in general? not just the value 'self'?

Comment: Then something like:

value:  "default-src 'self' https://xxxxx.com/; font-src https://fonts.gstatic.com/; img-src data: https://www.google-analytics.com/ https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/; script-src https://www.googletagmanager.com/ https://www.google-analytics.com/ https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/ 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src  https://fonts.googleapis.com/ 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'none'"

Comment: I tried using that way and I get the same result :(